# How to Build/Load a Table and Fill with Another Query as Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm mostly asking this to see if I'm going in the right direction since I'm new to this before I start researching how to do this.

I was provided a query that needs to be be the contents of the table below after building and loading the table. On SQL Server, should I make a temporary table for this with Select Into and fill that table with the query? Or is there an easier method?

the table:

http://puu.sh/gRF1N/86a1afad30.png

the query (I'm not sure what the bracketed "Attendance Reason" is either but I think it's associated with the custom table?):

```
SELECT
    dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.EMPLOYEE_ID ,
    dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON_CODE ,
    dbo_HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON.DESCRIPTION ,
    dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.EMP_ATTENDANCE_DATE ,
    dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.UNITS
FROM
    ( dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE
      LEFT JOIN dbo_HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON ON ( dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON_CODE = dbo_HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON.HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON_CODE )
                                            AND ( dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.INST_ID = dbo_HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON.INST_ID )
    )
    LEFT JOIN [ATTENDANCE REASON] ON dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.HR_ATTENDANCE_REASON_CODE = [ATTENDANCE REASON].Reason_Code
WHERE
    ( ( ( dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.EMP_ATTENDANCE_DATE ) >= '4/1/2014'
        AND ( dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.EMP_ATTENDANCE_DATE ) < '7/1/2014'
      )
      AND ( ( dbo_HR_EMPLOYEE_ATTENDANCE.FY ) = 2014 )
      AND ( ( [ATTENDANCE REASON].Reason_Direction ) = "u" )
    );
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that in SQL Server the brackets are necessary because the table name has a space in it. It's generally frowned upon to make tables or columns with a space in the name; I think it is not supported in all databases. But SQL Server lets you do it.

Comment: Why not make this a view instead of a table? It sounds like what you are describing is a view: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: Whether or not you turn this into a view is dependent on the performance of the query. If the speed is acceptable, you would be better served by a view because you wouldn't have to periodically update the table.